# Div : A Table Less Coding

Tags: html

I am a web Developer. Even I do web design but I use the TABLE method for HTML, I want to learn Tableless coding **(Div based)**.

Can anybody suggest me Few Best sites for learn Div Based Coding.

Comment: little too late to the game, isn't that? but better late than never, for sure.

Comment: Have you tried the net tuts they are gr8

Comment: Do you mean http://net.tutsplus.com/ my friend ?

Answer (score 1):

[A List Apart archives](http://www.alistapart.com/)

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp)

These would be my two recommendations to start. A List Apart does a good job explaining more about why it's important to markup this way.

Comment: I tried  on w3shools  but i did not got it there, they have only  one DIV  tag  in tag list  and its few attributes   
I exactly want  the complete tutorial  regarding  DIV...  
it will be a very big help to me my friend ,  ... And what is your second recommendations ... i got only one .
Thanks and Regards 
Raaj

Answer (score 0):

I tried to come up with a big list of things you should know, but I couldn't; it's not that much you need to know at all...

- First learn [how to use CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/)
- It's useful to know [how to use the CSS float-property](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/10/19/the-mystery-of-css-float-property/)
- And of course you may want to look at [an example layout](http://www.maxdesign.com.au/articles/liquid/liquid-sample3/)

Comment: Thanks Harmen 
I will try to finish it first  And later on i will tell you where am i and after that we will move to next step 
Thanks Alot